# How to disable a project in Tortoise SVN

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, tortoisesvn

My company is moving to TFS.  We are currently on Tortoise SVN.  I would like to be able to leave a project in SVN but some how disable it so people cannot commit changes but we can still see the history.

Up to this point, I've renamed a project and posted a message that it's currently in TFS and not to make changes.  The problem I have is, all the history is gone.  I would like to keep the history.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is deleting the project from SVN.  This makes it disappear but if you go back to previous revisions you will find the delete revision.  If you view that you are then able to pull down the latest version that was checked in but you are not able to commit changes.  You are also able to see all history from that point as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, "How do I make something in SVN read-only?", I have no idea. If you do a full history migration, there's less of a need for that.

You moved just the latest source code over to TFS, so of course you have no history. If you want to migrate the history out of SVN to TFS, the easiest way I've seen is to use Git as a go-between.

[Git natively supports SVN](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). [There are tools that allow Git and TFS to interoperate](https://gittf.codeplex.com/). Since you can get code from SVN into Git, and you can get code from Git into TFS, you can dump your SVN version history into Git, then migrate it from Git to TFS.

The basic process is this:

1. Use `git svn` to turn your SVN repository into a Git repository
2. Use [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) to hook your Git repository up to TFS and push the changes in.

This way, the history will be retained, however **timestamps will be lost**.

Of course, I'm assuming here that you're using TFVC. If you're using Git-in-TFS, it's even easier: Once you have your Git repository created from your SVN data, just force push it into TFS and you're done.

Comment: We are not doing a migration.  The main reason we are not doing a migration is because the projects were not setup correctly to begin with.  I basically had to rebuild the projects, then check them in to TFS.  We are also not using GIT.  All I really want to do is, make so it's very obvious in SVN that the project is not to be coded from there anymore and that you need to use the TFS version.  I don't know the correct strategy, more or less, I would have liked to some how disconnect all current checkouts of any given project so they would have to get it from TFS but retain the history IN SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Ok something i know about how to disable any commit or changes over the repository is by using a `start-commit` `hook` in the server
The hook is simply a `.bat` file with this content :

```
echo committing is disabled for that repository. >&2
exit 1
```

Name the file `start-commit.bat` and put it in the `hooks` folder of the repository.. Thats all.

**Note:**
This is a `windows` script.. For other servers you need another script.